# How to scan C++ code base and insert code in desired places?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I am interested in scanning and programmatically inserting a line of code to all googletest test cases in a code base like the following:

```
TEST(...) {
    RecordProperty("filename", __FILE__);
    ...
}
TEST_F(...) {
    RecordProperty("filename", __FILE__);
    ...
}
TEST_P(...) {
    RecordProperty("filename", __FILE__);
    ...
}
```

What are my options? What I want to achieve is to have an association between all test cases and their corresponding file. I'd also be open to other approaches other than the one I have above.

Comment: you could just do what googletest does and redefine the `TEST` macros. That's literally what happens there.

Comment: Aspect Oriented Programming for C++ Leveraging the Power of Simple Token Substitution Macros.  (Is there a laugh/cry emoji?  This is why I miss PostSharp.)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here -- The approach I went with was to define an [event listener](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html) like this:

```
class CustomTestEventListener : public ::testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
    void OnTestEnd(const testing::TestInfo& testInfo) override {
        testing::Test::RecordProperty("key", testInfo.file());
    }
}
```

This listener will effectively add a section in the generated gtest xml like this:

```
<testcase>
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="key" value=""/>
    </properties>
</testcase>
```